# Search classes from SWT UI in eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am currently building a UI based plugin that will generate some code. At some point I need choose which classes will be affected. At the moment I have a browse button where the user must search for the class file within the directory however this is quite cumbersome.

What I had in mind was what the  **Ctrl+Shift+T** does, therefore ***Open Type***. Does eclipse (luna) allow developers to integrate that particular feature in their plugins?

Comment: Are you trying to invoke the plugin using ctrl-shift-T or are you trying to use ctrl-shift-T once "inside" the tool?

Comment: what I want is that from within plugin UI, a particular field works as if I had pressed ctrl+shift+T. Hence, I search for the class and save its package, or path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably extend [TypeSelectionExtension](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fui%2Fdialogs%2FTypeSelectionExtension.html)